# Json.NET Primitive Types - use Decimal instead of Double

Tags: c#, json.net

How can I make JSON.NET return a decimal instead of a double when parsing floats from JSON? (it's an object with a `Dictionary<string,object>` that is serialized).

I've tried writing a JsonConverter but the CanConvert method doesn't get called with a Double type in order to try and convert it. There's other code regarding overriding JsonTextReader but this doesn't seem possible in the latest versions of Json.Net.

Comment: How are you reading the JSON? I'd expect if you had a class defined, with a `decimal` property, and used the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` method, it would deserialize just fine as a decimal.

Comment: Ah, sorry - Markdown munged my description - it's an object with IDictionary<string,object>

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In Json.NET 5.0, `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings` class has the new property `FloatParseHandling`, you can set this property value `Newtonsoft.Json.FloatParseHandling.Decimal`

Comment: Any hints on how to do this for a particular class or property? I.e. not to impact the global deserialization settings (also when I don't have access to those), but override this behavior in very specific places.