# Currency as string or currency as number?

Tags: c#, json, web-services, currency, currency-formatting

JSON web service: Whats the best way to output currency?

As a string OR

```
"Amount": "100.12345"
```

As an Number?

```
 "Amount": 100.12345
```

PayЗal and Google Checkout output json as a string. Why?

Comment: It depends on the use case.  String + is concatenation, although some shopkeeper may enjoy that $3 item plus $4 item is $34 the joke will only be funny one time. The only bad thing about numbers is they often need rounding.  Still I would go with number.

Answer (score 2):

I would do an integer of cents to keep it as simple as possible.

```
"Amount": 1045

...

var amount = json.amount/100;

...

amount === 10.45
```

Comment: You could also include properties "currency":'US$' and "currencyScale":0.01

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion use number until parsing in C# will be to decimal (not double). For more information you can look here 
[Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency)

If you are using JSON.NET see this thread [Json.NET Primitive Types - use Decimal instead of Double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617963/json-net-primitive-types-use-decimal-instead-of-double)

In JavaScript it doesn't matter what you use.